# Confused about memory management with retain/autorelease

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, retain, foundation

Lets say I have the following code:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) *SomeObject foo;
@property (nonatomic, retain) *SomeObject bar;

@synthesize foo, bar;

self.foo = [[SomeObject alloc] init];
self.bar = [[[SomeObject alloc] init] autorelease];

if (self.foo) {
    [self.foo release];
    self.foo = nil;
}

if (self.bar) {
    [self.bar release];
    self.bar = nil;
}
```

I get a memory leak with self.bar. I'm not exactly sure why, but I think it's because after calling [self.bar release], the object self.bar is pointing to gets autoreleased. When I nil out self.bar, we try to call release on the previous object (which got autoreleased), which creates the error. Is this correct? Also, are there other memory leaks, perhaps with foo?
What would be the correct fix?

Should I remove the release statements and just nil out both properties?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII If I were you, I would be glad someone actually bothers understanding how MRC works...

Comment: @h2co3 maybe. But at least read some articles or pick up a book instead of constantly posting the same questions with different property names over and over.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Was this directed towards me or OP? If you mean that, I **have** read TFM.

Comment: @H2CO3 sorry if that wasnt clear. I was refering to the OP. I know that you know objc, haha

Comment: Instead of a "memory leak", you have the opposite -- over-releasing of `self.bar`, which should lead to a crash or other undefined behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just use the accessors directly:

```
self.foo = [[[SomeObject alloc] init] autorelease];
self.bar = [[[SomeObject alloc] init] autorelease];

if (self.foo) {
    self.foo = nil;
}

if (self.bar) {
    self.bar = nil;
}
```

because the synthesized property accessors generate the code to perform reference count operations.

The form `[someObject.someProperty release]` should never be used.

The only place you should not use the accessors is in partially constructed states (i.e. initialization and `dealloc`). In that context, use direct access: `[ivar release], ivar = nil;`.

Comment: Thanks, could you also explain why the form [someObject.someProperty release] should never be used, but it's okay if we use the ivar? Isn't self.foo the same thing as foo except I call a method that returns foo? What would be the problem if I do this?

Comment: This is actually redundant: `if (self.foo) {
    self.foo = nil;
}`. Simply `self.foo = nil;` is easier to read and better style.

Comment: @Popcorn because the returned object may not be the same instance as the active ivar (e.g. concurrency and overriding are the typical scenarios). although you could guarantee that it were the same pointer in some restricted contexts, it's heavy maintenance and completely unnecessary. IOW, it erodes the correctness of the class' interface.

Comment: @torrey.lyons in most (not all) cases. however, i left it as-is in the event the OP's program relied on some implementation specific semantic difference. there's not enough context for me to know the significance of the test (if any).

Comment: @Popcorn: You should never use `[someObject.someProperty release]` because it is exactly the same as `[[someObject someProperty] release]`. Since your code snippet does not "own" the thing returned by the `someProperty` method (it does not start with `alloc`, `retain`, `new`, `copy`, or `mutableCopy`), you cannot release it.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 places wrong in your code:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) *SomeObject foo;
@property (nonatomic, retain) *SomeObject bar;

self.foo = [[SomeObject alloc] init]; // WRONG 1
self.bar = [[[SomeObject alloc] init] autorelease];

if (self.foo) {
    [self.foo release]; // WRONG 2
    self.foo = nil;
}

if (self.bar) {
    [self.bar release]; // WRONG 3
    self.bar = nil;
}
```

In any method, you must balance retains and releases, unless you are setting an instance variable on an object directly. You are not setting any instance variables here directly. You are using properties (which are method calls).

1 is wrong because `alloc` returns a retaining instance (you (this method) "own" it, thus you must release it before it goes out of your scope). You pass it to a method (the property setter) and then you no longer have a reference to it. Therefore it is leaked.

2 and 3 are wrong because you are releasing something you do not own. Property access is a method call, and normal method calls do not return retaining instances.

The errors 1 and 2 happen to balance out -- there are so many things wrong that they happen to achieve the right result, in a wrong way. Error 3 should cause a crash in your program, because you are over-releasing.